# Sending simple data with notification to another app

Tags: android, mysql, message

I'm working on two seperate apps that need at some point to exchange messages, both apps share a MYSQL database, I want the first app to be able to send some data to one of the other app's users (specified by his id, email or phone number ), and this last to be able to reply to the request by accepting or rejecting with a button click.

Now, I don't know what is the best:

- Something similar to chat ?Is it possible to extract the necessary data from the rest of the chat message ?
- A broadcast.
- A push notification.
- Or something else ?

Help me please I'm a total newbie, I would use an expert opinion.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is basically every other Chat App that exists.
I can only suggest you to read this code example to get an idea how to approach this:

- [Android Chat Example code](https://github.com/pusher-community/android-chat-example)

Comment: I have edited my question , apparently it wasn't quite clear. Sir, the example you gave me uses a twitter account is there a way to replcae it with an email !! Thanks in advance